# MongoDB : Match one object with a new column and get a combined new data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am making an app where I will set number of quiz sets, which will carry number of questions, options and correct answers.

The individual question will appear to user as a form with no answer, and the soon user will select option and submit the form it will go to another data set named "Answers". each answer object will carry the "participated_user_id", "quiz_id", "answers". The answer will carry each "question_id" and "user_answer".

Now I want some query which will club these two data sets and in "quiz" set add "user_answer" after each question.

## QUIZ

```
{
_id : 856803,
title : My quiz title,
active : on,
questions : [
  {
    _id : 135224,
    options : [a, b c, d],
    question : here is my question one ?,
    answer : a,
  },
  {
    _id : 135229,
    options : [a, b c, d],
    question : here is my question two ?,
    answer : a,
  }
 ]
}
```

## ANSWERS

```
{
  _id : 1234,
  quiz_id : 856803,
  answers : [
     {
        _id: 2367,
        question_id : 135224,
        answer : a
     } ,
     {
        _id: 2364,
        question_id : 135229,
        answer : c
     } 
  ]
}
```

## I Want

```
{
_id : 856803,
title : My quiz title,
active : on,
questions : [
  {
    _id : 135224,
    options : [a, b c, d],
    question : here is my question one ?,
    answer : a,
    user_answer : a
  },
  {
    _id : 135229,
    options : [a, b c, d],
    question : here is my question two ?,
    answer : a,
    user_answer : c
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: can any one please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('quiz').findOne({}, function(err, doc){

     db.getCollection('answers').findOne({quiz_id : doc._id}, function(err, ans){

        doc.questions.forEach( function( item) {

             for( let i = 0; i < ans.answers.length; i++ ) {
                  if( ans.answers[i].question_id === item._id )
                      item.user_answer = ans.answers[i].answer;            

              }

         })

     })
  let _id = doc._id
  delete doc._id // for handling duplicate key error in update
  db.getCollection( 'quiz' ).update({_id: _id}, doc, function(err, result){

                 console.log( "doc updated as per your requirements")
   })

})
```

Comment: thank you so very much sir helped me quite a lot. I am totaly new to this , so If you allow can I ask one more ?

Comment: Sure. And if it helped a lot to you then accept this answer

Comment: Yes sir I have followed the way you instructed.
here is my another struggle since last night https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059355/express-node-js-controller-not-waiting-for-data-manipulation-and-returning-old-d

Comment: Ok. Sure.  I will answer that question as best as possible. So accept this answer. So that it will help others too

Comment: Ok sorry I am totally new, I was not getting it when you said to accept the answer ! , feels so blessed to finally having such a contact like you atleast I can ask or share my points :)