# Express node.js controller not waiting for data manipulation and returning old data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using express.js , node.js to connect mongoDB.

## My aim

I have a **quiz-collection**. I have an **answers-collection****.
When I am showing the user the quiz list, I want to show the user if he/she has already participated in any of the quizzes.

## My way

1. I added a Boolean field to each document in quiz collection as **"user_participated" : false**      .
2. When my route calls "/all-quizzes", it calls a function from controller, which first sets all the document "user_participated" false in side a forEach, then as per current "user_id" and "quiz_id" finds one data from "answers" collection inside the same forEach, and if it exists then it set the quiz document's **"user_participated" to true**. then it returns the whole data.

## My problem

in controller function soon it finds all quiz documents, it does not wait till the **'forEach'** gets executed and returns that data then it executes the **'forEach'**.
so when I refresh the page again I can see the manipulations that I made.

## HERE IS MY CODE

```
exports.getAllQuiz = async function(req, res){
    var newQuiz = new Quiz; // declaring that newQuiz is an instance of quiz helper
    try{
        var finalQuizs = await newQuiz.findAll();
        var authToken = req.cookies.auth; // getting the logged in user token
        var autherised_user = '';
        if(authToken != undefined && authToken != null && authToken.trim().length > 0){
            jwt.verify(authToken, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
                else {
                    autherised_user = decoded.id;
                    finalQuizs.forEach(async function(item){
                        // first I am setting all the document's user_participated value to false
                        await quizModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id : ObjectId(item._id)}, {user_participated : false});

                        // now I am setting selected documents user_participated to true as per current user
                        // for that I am checking in answer collection if a data is present with
                        // current user id and this quiz id
                        await AnswerModel.findOne({quiz_id : item._id, participated_user_id : autherised_user}, async function(err, result){
                            if(result != null){
                                await quizModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id : ObjectId(item._id)}, {user_participated : true});
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return finalQuizs;
    }catch(e){

    }
};
```

Comment: I don't really know what's going on in your code here, You should try splitting your logic into smaller discrete parts (for example you could extract the JWT authentication to a separate middleware).  Also, I think you should not do this `await quizModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id : ObjectId(item._id)}, {user_participated : false})`    `user_participated ` can be set to false on the quiz model by default no?

Comment: yes by default it is false only. But think in other way that If I dont make it false here and some documents are already manipulated by other user then ? it will show the current user that he has participated. so every time for a user I am setting it to false then making it true as per current user id

Comment: finalQuizs needs to be dependent on the full resolution of the  async process surrounding the updates. If you were to track where update promises ACTUALLY resolve vs where the 'return finalQuizes' gets invoked, it may surprise you

Comment: Thank you ! @RobertRowntree I searched after your instruction and found some way to apply promise resolve. Though I am a beginner not sure about my code but its now working ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your return value `finalQuizs` is filled before the `forEach` statement. So the update queries does not change it as you expect. This is the reason of getting updated data after the page refresh.
If you expect to have `user_participated: true` in the returned value, you should get it after `findOneAndUpdate` line. 
You should do something like this at the end of `try` block:

```
return await newQuiz.findAll();
```

Comment: Yes sir tried this also , not working ! still waiting for a page refresh .